# Dagger 2 injecting object

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have made an android bottom bar in activity and thought i'd use dagger2 to set listener for it. How ever I am confused as to how to get the **getSupportFragmentManager()** inside the listener class.
Here's what i'm trying

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@BindView(R.id.bottomNavigationView)
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    BottomBarComponent bottomBarComponent = DaggerBottomBarComponent.builder()
            .bottomBarModule(new BottomBarModule(getSupportFragmentManager()))
            .build();

}
}
```

The component part is

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {BottomBarModule.class})
public interface BottomBarComponent {
 void inject(BottomNavigationListener listener);
}
```

The module is

```
@Module
public class BottomBarModule {
private FragmentManager manager;

public BottomBarModule(FragmentManager context) {
    this.manager = context;
}

@Singleton
@Provides
public FragmentManager provideSupportManager(){
    return manager;
}
}
```

And need to get fragmentsupportManager here

```
public class BottomNavigationListener implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{


@Inject
FragmentManager manager;

public void BottomNavigationListener() {

   //somehow need to get fragmentSupportManager here
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    return true;
}
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to share instance of `BottomBarComponent` with your `BottomNavigationListener` and invoke `inject()` method on it.

*BottomNavigationListener.class*

```
...
public void BottomNavigationListener(BottomBarComponent injector) {
   //somehow need to get fragmentSupportManager here
   injector.inject(this); // now manager field must be filled
}
...
```

*MainActivity.class*

```
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    BottomBarComponent bottomBarComponent = DaggerBottomBarComponent.builder()
            .bottomBarModule(new BottomBarModule(getSupportFragmentManager()))
            .build();
    // pass BottomBarComponent to BottomNavigationListener for injecting FragmentManager
    BottomNavigationListener listener = new BottomNavigationListener(bottomBarComponent);
}
...
```

But very strange thing you're trying to do. It's all equivalent to passing `FragmentManager` directly to `BottomNavigationListener` without using Dagger.

Comment: SInce you say its equivalent to passing, how do i change implementation using dagger?

Comment: I mean it's overkill to use dagger for such case.

Comment: Why did you decide to use Dagger?